# Broken x and y-axes in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, yaxis, x-axis

I am trying to plot broken y and x axis. I wrote a very basic code taking help from previous answered questions. However, I fail to understand why my plot is not taking the left of broken x-axis and down of broken y-axis. I am attaching my data file here for [a.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7o1ucq9tlk3ygcp/a.txt?dl=0) and [b.dat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n7xfom5gb1pfrig/b.dat?dl=0). My code reads as

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import *
import matplotlib as mpl
import os
from math import ceil
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes


path = os.getcwd()+"/"
symm_type="eb"
flag_include_other_limits=True

mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize']=20
mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelsize']=20
mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize']=20
mpl.rcParams['legend.borderpad']=0.8
mpl.rcParams['ps.fonttype']=42
mpl.rcParams['pdf.fonttype']=42
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
mpl.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman'] + plt.rcParams['font.serif']

print("Plot_Limit_M_G: Plotting limits on (m,g)...")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[9,9])
bax = brokenaxes(xlims=((1e-35, 1e-10), (1e-3, 1e1)), ylims=((1e-32, 1e-24), (1e-6, 1e-3)), hspace=.05)
bax_xticks_major = np.array([1.e-35, 1.e-30, 1.e-25, 1.e-20, 1.e-15, 1.e-10, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1e1])
bax.set_xscale('log')
bax.set_yscale('log')
x = np.logspace(-35, 1, 100)
y = np.logspace(-32, -3,100)
lst_colors = ['#f51d11', '#08c252', '#11a9f5', '#FF00FF', '#b166d1']
lst_styles = ['-', '--', ':', '--', '.-']

lst_limits3 = Read_Data_File(path+"b.dat")
lst_m3 = [ 10.**lst_limits3[0][j] for j in range(len(lst_limits3[0])) ]
lst_g_hi_20153 = [10.**lst_limits3[1][j] for j in range(len(lst_limits3[1]))]
bax.plot(lst_m3, lst_g_hi_20153, color='#FF00FF', ls='dashed', lw=2.5, zorder=20)

lst_limits5 = Read_Data_File(path+"a.txt")
lst_m5 = [ 10.**lst_limits5[0][j] for j in range(len(lst_limits5[0])) ]
lst_g_hi_20155 = [10.**lst_limits5[1][j] for j in range(len(lst_limits5[1]))]
bax.plot(lst_m5, lst_g_hi_20155, color='#b166d1', ls='dashed', lw=2.5, zorder=20)

pylab.savefig("outfile.pdf", bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)
plt.show()
plt.close()
path = os.getcwd()+"/"
```

I tried the above code and was expecting for the plot to range from 10^{-35} to 10^{-10}in x-axis then break and again start from 10^{-3} to 10^{1}. Along y-axis I wanted it to show from 10^{-32} to 10^{-24} then break and show from 10^{-6} to 10^{-3}. But it is not showing.

Comment: I wonder if the little answers you've received depend on the intimidating nature of your piece of code (all those `import`s!), as well as its non-replicability (no data is provided). I guess if you work to produce a [mre] you could get much more help, and possibly solve your issue on your own…

Comment: @gboffi I did attach my data file in a.txt and b.dat. If you click them you can download those data files. Regarding the imports, the script I give here is a very small script of the whole. I did not clear everything before copying here. I am sorry for that. But please help.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html The idea is to plot the same data on two axes, followed by setting the visibility of different parts of the axes.

Comment: I've installed `brokenaxes` and I tried to replicate your setup — the results were not exactly satisfying (mostly some misalignment) but overall I've got a reasonable output. The most important difference with your code is that ① I specified (per the introductory example) the logaritmicity when instantiating the broken axes, and ② I've used (again, per the introductory example) `bax.loglog(...)` in place of `bax.plot(...)`

Comment: @gboffi can you please elaborate a little more? Like when you say you introduced the logarithmicity before, what exactly does that mean? I am relatively new to python and it is kind of difficult to understand.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/brokenaxes/ — scroll down until the paragraph "Log scales", I copied that code and placed your xlimits, ylimits in it, then I plotted some fake stuff and it _almost_ worked fine.

Comment: @gboffi I followed the same example for this script and I am not able to get even the same frame with my x and y limits. I have written my problem explicitly. I am not able to get left part of x-axis and down part of y-axis. I am only getting my x-axis and y-axis after the broaken part. Can you atleast send me the frame code, if you are able to produce that. I can take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, sort of, with your limits for the partial axes. There are a number of annoying artifacts but, fundamentally, it works.

[image]

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes
from numpy import logspace

x = logspace(-35, +1, 100)
y = logspace(-32, -3, 100)

fig = figure()
bax = brokenaxes(xlims=((1E-35, 1E-10), (1E-3, 10)),
                 ylims=((0.8E-32, 1E-24), (1E-6, 2e-3)),
                 xscale='log', yscale='log')
bax.loglog(x, y, label='...')
bax.legend(loc=8)
bax.grid(axis='both', which='major', ls='-')
bax.set_xlabel('x')
bax.set_ylabel('y')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for this. At least now I can reproduce the frame, probably I will be able to carry forward with my data. Thanks again! However, we do not see minor tics in logscale in y or x axis. Is there a way I can fix this? I tried mentioning it explicitly like in my code if you see, 'xtics_major'. But it is not working. I only have tics in above yaxis.

Comment: As I wrote _"There are a number of annoying artifacts"_. I think that you must patch the code of `brokenaxes` or go down to the fundamentals, using only Matplotlib per [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html).